# watchman.plist permission denied when running a react-native initial project

Tags: node.js, react-native, watchman

I'm start using react-native and I followed the tutorials on the website, but when running the example project, it returned some error messages on the terminal:

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/username/Desktop/nativeTest/BookSearch 

[06:03:00] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[06:03:00] <START> Crawling File System
[06:03:00] <START> Loading bundles layout
[06:03:00] <END>   Loading bundles layout (0ms)

React packager ready.

2015-12-13T06:03:01,281: [cli] Failed to open /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

2015-12-13T06:03:01,281: [cli] Failed to open /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

Watchman:  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2015-12-13T06:03:01,281: [cli] Failed to open /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

 ERROR  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2015-12-13T06:03:01,281: [cli] Failed to open /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

Error: watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2015-12-13T06:03:01,281: [cli] Failed to open /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/nativeTest/BookSearch/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:194:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:88:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:173:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:819:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:320:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:78:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:170:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:470:12)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.
~
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I tried to chmod com.github.facebook.watchman.plist but actually there's no such file there. Maybe I should change the path of the file?

Other things I've tried:

1. brew update
2. brew upgrade watchman
3. brew uninstall watchman && brew install --HEAD watchman
4. Restart and reinit the project

Packages Version (if needed):

1. node: v5.2.0
2. watchman: v4.2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that `/Users/username/Library` and `/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents` are owned by `username` and have the correct permissions; here's how mine look:

```
$ ls -ld ~/Library
drwx------+ 57 wez  users  1938 Nov  6 07:49 /Users/wez/Library
$ ls -ld ~/Library/LaunchAgents
drwxr-xr-x  3 wez  users  102 Dec 11 16:13 /Users/wez/Library/LaunchAgents
$ ls -l ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 wez  users  1545 Dec 11 16:13 /Users/wez/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
```

Also make sure that you don't run watchman as root or via sudo.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks! I didn't realize that the plist file will be created the first time running watchman, `~/Library/LaunchAgent` was still owned by root.

Comment: mine is different. How do I solve it
`$ ls -ld ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 muhaimincs  staff  46 Aug 16 11:03 /Users/muhaimincs/Library/LaunchAgents -> /usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

Comment: this is what I miss `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist`. You can see my question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912523/error-watchman-no-pretty-get-sockname-when-run-npm-start

Comment: run  -$sudo chown <username> ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Answer (score 23):

Current user do not have permission on folder `/Users/[username]/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Use the following command to fix this:

```
$ sudo chown $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/Library/LaunchAgents
```