# React-Native: Failed to load bundle. Cannot read property 'throwlfClosureRequired'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The app installs and opens but right when it opens this red screen appears with the below error message.

TBH I am not quite sure what I am doing and I really need some help. I was able to get my other project to work but when I started my second project this came up when trying to run the code. The code is just the basic code you get when you run: react-native init projectName

[image: Error when trying to setup project in react-native.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the version of "babel-preset-react-native" to "4.0.0". For the lastest version 5.0.0, the issue arises.

1. Run npm install after the version change. Then start the emulator.
2. Even then if you face issue, delete your node_modules directory, repeat step 1.
3. Restart your machine if you see the issue again even after all tries.

Check [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18962)

Answer (score 4):

I got the above mentioned error just now. I am using React Native v0.57 and my json file had this

```
 {
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I added "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0", and removed "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.6" in the "devDependencies" and the error was resolved.

Comment: I am using react native 0.51.1, and facing the same issue like you. I have changed the package.json file as you described. And run npm install again. But still getting an error while running it.  Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan's solution worked for me as well:

Fixed. babel pushed an update that pushed to 5.0.0. set your presets to 4.0.0 and it will fix it.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18962

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded to

"react-native": 0.57.7

"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.5",

Now the bundle is loading as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My current version:

"react-native": "0.57.8",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",

Here how I fixed:

1. add

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0"
   },
   ```
2. remove `node_modules`
3. `npm install`

Voilà! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. babel pushed an update that pushed to 5.0.0. set your presets to 4.0.0 and it will fix it.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18962

Answer (score 0):

^^ what they said...  change your "babel-preset-react-native" to 4.0.0 .

Comment: yes! that's all you gotta do and then run npm install in the folder

Comment: Tried all but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
react-native upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Downgrading to  "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0", did not work. 
running this worked for me

npm add @babel/runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:
clean the build folder and try again.

**run react-native start --reset-cache in one tab**

and then
**run react-native in another tab**

Answer (score 0):

For me this answer worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966360/4483716

Basically I needed to give permission to folder

> /Users/[username]/Library/LaunchAgents.

**Use this command:**

```
$ sudo chown $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `babel-preset-react-native` version 4.0.0 to your `devDependencies` in `package.json`

`"devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0"
    },`

2. `npm install`
3. `react-native run-ios` or android

If it still doesn't work try `rm -rf node_modules/` and redo step 2 & 3