# react-native run-ios. Failed to load bundle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I know this question has been asked before however after numerous days trying to get it figured out, I'm still stumped. I have followed help from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18962 as well as [React-Native: Failed to load bundle. Cannot read property 'throwlfClosureRequired'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951233/react-native-failed-to-load-bundle-cannot-read-property-throwlfclosurerequire/49954642)

Unfortunately after following these steps and trying different things, I still can't seem to get it to work.

I have changed my package.json from:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
```

to

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
```

I've tried deleting node_modules and doing npm install. I have restarted my computer multiple times and still haven't gotten anything to work

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.2
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
yarn: 1.10.1
watchman: 4.9.0
node: 9.6.1
npm: 6.4.1
xcode: 10.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide any more information that would be of use.

Comment: UPDATE: I finally got it to work by going into my project folder and doing the following command: “yarn upgrade react-native@0.57.1”

Comment: Going to keep this open incase someone else has a similar issue,

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I finally got it to work by going into my project folder and doing the following command: “yarn upgrade react-native@0.57.1”