# Watchman: watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=null, signal=SIGABRT, stderr

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest but whenever I do `npm test` I get errors. I tried Googling didn't find any solution

Macbook-2:JSProj abhimanyuaryan$ npm test

```
> jsproj@1.0.0 test /Users/abhimanyuaryan/Desktop/JSProj  
> jest                                                    

2018-05-08T12:40:57,551: [cli] Failed to open /Users/abhim
anyuaryan/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchma
n.plist for write: Not a directory                        

Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with
 exit code=null, signal=SIGABRT, stderr= 2018-05-08T12:40:
57,551: [cli] Failed to open /Users/abhimanyuaryan/Library
/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write
: Not a directory
```

Comment: Try `brew install watchman`

Comment: @mpontus watchman is already installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [watchman.plist permission denied when running a react-native initial project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245678/watchman-plist-permission-denied-when-running-a-react-native-initial-project)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Library` folder.  Is `LaunchAgents` a file or a folder?  In my case it was a file, but needed to be a folder.  When I deleted the file and created a folder of the same name the Jest tests started working