# Error: EMFILE: too many open files - React Native CLI

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I try to run a react-native-cli project using react-native start, and the metro bundler fails, saying the following:

```
events.js 187
throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch

Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher isntance at:
     at NodeWatcher: checkedEmitError (.../react-native-project/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:143:12)
     at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:210:5)
     at FSEvent.FSWatcher:_handle onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:129:12) {
   errno: -24,
   syscall: 'watch',
   code : 'EMFILE',
   filename: null
)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

Comment: Please mark my answer correct it it helped you

Comment: I was still having issues after trying your solution.

Comment: try setting ulimit on terminal:  ulimit 4096

Comment: Switching to node 16 fixed the issue for me `nvm alias default 16`

Comment: @Amir Did you get any solution to fix above too many open files issue? Even we are facing it on react native 0.63.3 and ventura mac os.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In my case, upgrading watchman did not help.

This problem started to happen after having updated Node.js.

Thanks to `nvm`, I came back to node v8.11.3 (I updated to v12.0.4) and this issue disappeared.

That might help some of you having the same problem...

Comment: This was indeed what was happening for me as well. I had just upgraded from Node `10.16.2` to the latest LTS (at the time of this writing `12.16.1`) and ran into this. I bumped the `.nvmrc` back down to `10.16.2` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Same here. Darn Node 12.

Comment: I believe this was the fix for me.  downgrading Node fixed the issue for me

Comment: Node v14.17.4 has the same error for me. @MarceloSouza, could you please let me know your exact node version? thanks in advance.

Comment: reinstall `node_modules` after changing the node version if you previously installed them with the broken version

Comment: @John T  Did you'll get any solution to fix above too many open files issue? Even we are facing it on react native 0.63.3 and ventura mac os. Is it because of incompatibility between react native and newest version of ventura macos?

Answer (score 112):

Just close all other files and try again. If you are running on android make sure to run `cd android` and `./gradlew clean` before `react-native run-android`. 
If this doesn't fix, there might be problem with your file watching service. Try this

```
$ brew update
$ brew install watchman
```

Comment: I'm running on ios.  and I don't have any files running that I can see

Comment: This issue is not specific to React. I hit upon this issue when running `Jest`. Looks like this is an `iOS` issue. When `watchman` is installed, the tools seem to use it for watching file changes. Watchman can watch large number of files. Therefore, installing it most probably would solve the issue.

Comment: this issue raised for me, because I have two react-native projects running in different directories with different versions.
`brew upgrade watchman` 
helped me

Comment: In Catalina sometimes watchman does not have permission to access Document folder where the projects are, so it gives this error, make sure you have required permission given else try removing and adding watchman again.

Comment: Running `brew reinstall watchman` finally fixed the error for me (had to do `xcode-select --install` for it to work too). It asked for permission to access Document folder after I did that.

Comment: Worked for me, I am using Bigsur with Mac M1 and I upgraded from nodejs 16 to 17 (rather composer did) 
I had this issue and installing watchman with `arch -arm64 brew install watchman`  helped me , I'm commenting incase anyone ran into the same issue

Comment: Watchman is used instead of Nodewatcher on macOS. If you see errors about Nodewatcher in the future and you're using macOS then you need to install Watchman.

Comment: I am facing this issue while running gitlab pipeline, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 52):

I'm using a Mac and got the EMFile error. It was resolved when I installed the file watcher

`brew install watchman`

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Macbook pro M1 chip MacOS Big Sur. Node version is 14.16.0. I was having the issue while working with React native project created using Expo. `brew install watchman` worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This is what worked for me :
1 - delete node modules
2 - brew reinstall watchman
3 - install node modules
4 - then try building the project

Answer (score 25):

For my case, I think this error occurs due to node upgrade.

Delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` solved the issue.

Comment: node upgrade was the issue for me. This solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 18):

I needed to install `watchman` with `brew` as others have done here, however I also needed to update the `React Native Xcode build script` with this line: `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` so xCode could find `watchman` in my M1 MacBook Pro.

React Native Xcode build script location: `./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh`

Comment: This fixed it for me. Had installed watchman and it fixed the error when running on the command line, but Xcode still threw the error as apparently it didn't know it was installed. Added the `export PATH` command in front of the build script call and it works now.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using a MAC and Node v12.13.1. I upgraded watchman and the issue got resolved.

`watchman 4.9.0_2 -> 4.9.0_4`

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue after upgrading my node version. Downgrading was not an option in my case.

`brew install watchman` did not fix the issue, as watchman was already installed on my machine. `brew upgrade watchman` did the trick for me.

Comment: This command: "brew upgrade watchman" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

TLTR: `brew install watchman` solved it on a Macbook.

I just got a new Macbook and was having the same issue with a React Native project. On Windows the project was working perfectly but in Mac, after a few seconds of running the project with npm start, it crashed with this error:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:178:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

PS: `npm install` didn't work. It has to be with `brew install`.

Comment: How does this solve the issue? Is it related to the Node version?

Comment: I have a Macbook Air M1 with node 14.17.0, and for some reason I was having the above mentioned error when trying to run the expo app. Installing Watchman fixed the error. I guess that maybe the watchman version that came with Node was older than the required.

Answer (score 6):

No matter what I did, I couldn't get this to work.
What ended up working for me is using the following command

```
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=10485760
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1048576
```

Found at: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#mac-os-file-descriptor-limits

I have a M1 Pro.
Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! it solved my issue. Even though the documentation mentions those are only applicable on macOS 10.6 and **earlier**, they worked in my case (macOS 13.0).

Answer (score 4):

Tried everything but nothing changed.

After 2 days ->

Just ***killall node*** and

restart your computer and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, a simple `upgrade watchman` didn't help, and neither did changing my Node version.

I was building on an M1 Mac using XCode 12.5 and had to:

- Install watchman on using an x86_64 instance of homebrew
- Run the metro server in a Rosetta terminal
- Run XCode **without** Rosetta

If this is the first time you're installing a package using the x86_64 instance of homebrew remember to add it to your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Try "brew install watchman" command,

if "brew" not install then follow below steps

Follow [this steps](https://5balloons.info/correct-way-to-install-and-use-homebrew-on-m1-macs/), This is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of these errors along with others like Could not find "Podfile.lock", etc. after installing PHP Storm.

I did the following to correct the errors based off a combination of StackOverflow searches:

1. Download, install, and agree to the XCode license
2. Install brew via the terminal window at brew.sh
3. Install node
4. Followed the instructions in the iOS terminal window in PHPStorm

Now working!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me on MacOS:

1. Updating/Installing Homebrew from official site https://brew.sh/
2. Installing Watchman: b*rew install watchman*

Answer (score 1):

I had watchman installed via `macports`. However the path to watchman was unknown to to the "Bundle React Native code and images" Build Phase.
Adding

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

to the beginning of the script fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case that was both `node_modules` and `node` itself, so I downgraded node to 16 and reinstalled `node_modules` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error after switching dev machines from Linux to OS X. None of the above worked for me until I ran `brew upgrade watchman`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with couple of node versions but giving same error.

`brew update watchman`

helped to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the icu4c version was wrong. I reinstall `icu4c` then it's worked. Here is the command which I used:

```
 brew reinstall icu4c
```

Answer (score 0):

Works inside docker: ulimit -n 2048

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check that `~/Library` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents` are owned by your user. In my case, `~/Library/LaunchAgents` was owned by `root` which was preventing `watchman` from writing to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist`. This was not immediately obvious as `watchman` was being used indirectly through a local dev server which suppressed the helpful error. I ultimately identified the issue by manually attempting to watch my project.

```
    # Attempt manual watch of project, logs helpful error that was suppressed by local dev server
    watchman watch-project /path/to/your/project
    # Permissions error
    [cli] Failed to open /Users/<your_user>/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Permission denied

    # check Library ownership
    ls -ld ~/Library
    # root owns Library
    drwx------@ 87 root  staff  2784 Jan 23 09:42 /Users/<your_user>/Library
    # fix Library ownership
    sudo chown $(id -u) ~/Library

    # check LaunchAgents ownership
    ls -ld ~/Library/LaunchAgents
    # root owns LaunchAgents
    drwxr-xr-x@ 4 root  staff  128 Jan 26 09:05 /Users/<your_user>/Library/LaunchAgents
    # fix LaunchAgents ownership
    sudo chown $(id -u) ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

This fix is also explained in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245678/watchman-plist-permission-denied-when-running-a-react-native-initial-project/34248093#34248093)

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, watchman was located at `/opt/homebrew/bin/watchman`. Adding a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/watchman` worked for me:

```
sudo ln /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman /usr/local/bin/watchman
```

Answer (score 0):

On mac, these 2 commands can help you:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install watchman
```