# How to fix Too many open files error in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using React Native 40.0.1 and I am getting the following error when running `yarn start` or `expo start`:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:204:21)
```

I've tried `brew install watchman` as this was suggested by multiple GH issues and SO posts that I visited. This didn't fix the issue.

I'm using NodeJS `16.14.2` (expo doesn't officially support 17) with expo-cli `5.4.12`.

`package.json` and `yarn.lock` can be found on this GitHub Gist:

https://gist.github.com/DillonB07/5ea28e083074333879bae52b6134ee2c

My OS is macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with an Intel Chip.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59679356/19330634

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: EMFILE: too many open files - React Native CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675179/error-emfile-too-many-open-files-react-native-cli)

Comment: No, neither of those help. (I found them before posting this) I think I have the same issue but none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

Comment: Try this also https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/923#issuecomment-884837704

Comment: Thanks, but that's not eligible for me. I'm not using the iOS emulator as I don't have XCode. I'm using an Android emulator. It's also not just Android that's the issue. It's the web server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I updated my dependencies. I was using old dependencies because they were supposed to work for my project, but apparently there was an issue somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by watchman.

You should run brew install watchman in the terminal.

If watchman fails to install, you should change the ownership of these directories to your user by

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/usr/local/var/log

please refer to the tips in your terminal.

Finally you run brew install watchman. The problem should be solved..